# Selecting random index in array & calling variable from different function. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, variables

I am have trouble accessing the random index that is being chosen through randomTest. When I call randomTest in analytics_test(), I receive an undefined error. I feel as if I am not actually accessing this variable. Any tips or ideas to fix this problem? I would appreciate it, thank you!

```
//This function creates a loop for 5 random numbers. Each index in the array is given a variable
function createTest_Var() {
    var testNumber = [];
    var i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        testNumber[i] = (Math.random() * 10);
   }
 var randomTest = testNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * testNumber[i].length)]; 
return testNumber;
}
//This function takes chooses a random index from the array and compares it to the random number "y".
function analytics_test() {
    var y = (Math.random() * 10);
    var i = createTest_Var.randomTest;
        if (y < i) {
         //Just a test console.log ("the random numbers are: " + (Math.random() * 10));
            console.log ("It is greater! " + i + "<" + y);
        }
        else {
            console.log("not big enough " + i + ">" + y);
        }
}
```

Comment: `var i = createTest_Var.randomTest;` --- what does this statement do? And why do you have 2 returns in `createTest_Var`?

Comment: I set i equal to the "random index" that it is suppose to access in createTest_Var(). I wanted to try to compare that random number to Y in the function analytics_test(). Also, I have two return statements because I was just testing around my code, I'll remove the second one.

Comment: I don't mean to be mean but I think you need to work through a couple of JavaScript tutorials. Having a `var` statement after a `return` basically does nothing. It certainly doesn't add a property to a function that you can access outside of the function.

Comment: How come `randomTest ` is assigned after a return statement? Can you provide a code sample on JSFiddle\JSBin?

Comment: @NeilDCruz that was an accident on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- `randomTest` never gets its value, because you exit the function before reaching that code. But even if you would move the `return` statement after it, it would not be accessible from outside the function body.
- you never execute the function `createTest_Var`. The code `createTest_Var.randomTest` tries to access an unexisting property of the function object. To call the function you should write `createTest_Var()`
- Even if you would call it you are still not actually picking a random element from the generated array because of the first issue. For this you could write a separate function, and call it like this: `pickFromArray(createTest_Var())`
- `testNumber[i].length` is not correct: you want the length of the array, not its i-th element, so write `testNumber.length`.

Here is the code corrected:

```js
//This function creates a loop for 5 random numbers. Each element in the array is given a value
function createTest_Var() {
  var testNumber = [];
  var i; 
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    testNumber[i] = (Math.random() * 10);
  }
  return testNumber;
}

// Function to pick random element from array
function pickFromArray(testNumber) {
  return testNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * testNumber.length)]; 
}

//This function takes chooses a random element from the array and compares it to the random number "y".
function analytics_test() {
  var y = (Math.random() * 10);
  var i = pickFromArray(createTest_Var());
  if (y < i) {
    //Just a test console.log ("the random numbers are: " + (Math.random() * 10));
    console.log ("It is greater! " + i + "<" + y);
  }
  else {
    console.log("not big enough " + i + ">" + y);
  }
}

analytics_test();
```

Comment: thank you so much! that was a stupid mistake on my - exiting the function before declaring randomTest. That truly helped a low, just with the overall understanding of what I was doing wrong. Thanks again.